# Could a Play Store family plan block apps abroad on my Google account

Tags: applications, google-play-store, localization

**Background:**

I have a problem with region-blocked apps.

After moving abroad I must download region-specific banking and eid apps and after changing my Play Store Region, paying methods, clearing cache, and memory I still can't access the applications I need.

Interestingly, when I log my old university e-mail on Play Store I can access all the apps I need even though this Google account has no Paying methods and not even a registered address.

**Question:**

Is the account I want to use having its access deferred because of a Google Music Family Plan subscription from the country I travelled from.

Even if I'm not the Family Plan manager could this payment block apps where I am now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently yes.

Google family subscription can cause your Play Store to not recognize a new area you are in. I suppose it has to do with certain group permissions such as sharing Play Store settings and app versions.

Anyway, after quiting the Google family group I was in, my Play Store showed the apps I needed.